# How did the Z80 instruction set differ from the 8080?

Tags: z80, 8080, instruction-set

The Zilog Z80 microprocessor, known for its use in the ZX Spectrum, was designed to be a backwards-compatible extension to the Intel 8080 processor. It introduced several new instructions to the 8080's instruction set, as well as adding or extending registers.

But, as those of us who've used undocumented opcodes know, you can never add without taking. [Every change breaks *someone's* <s>workflow</s>](//xkcd.com/1172/) program. So what are the differences between the instruction sets of these two "compatible" chips?

Comment: Irrelevant to the question but did you know that the Z80 is used in the Ti series calculators and the Nintendo Gameboy?

Comment: @a25bedc5-3d09-41b8-82fb-ea6c353d75ae I knew about the Ti series, but not the Gameboy. Thanks for that information!

Comment: If you count the original processor, its clones and descendants, the Z80 was, and probably still is, the best-selling microprocessor in history.  It was used in the TRS-80, Commodore 128, scads of systems that ran CP/M, several game consoles (Colecovision among them) and stand-up arcade games and innumerable embedded applications.  The year marks 40 years that the family has been in production.

Comment: @wizzwizz4, a, late, note about the technical language: when considering processor, computer architecture is usually considered to have two aspects: instruction set architecture (the programmer view, think x86) and micro-architecture (internal organization, think non programmer-visible changes between two generations). There is a third aspect which does not have an established name, which is about things like process node, cache size and other optional or configurable parts, ...

Comment: Even relying on some invalid operation, happening as a side effect of some efficient way to do something intended, to fail can break someone's workflow if things unexpectedly succeed.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

For the most part the Z-80 extends the 8080 instruction set.  If we consider just the 8080 instructions themselves there are a few incompatibilities:

1. Overflow flag.  On the 8080 bit 2 of the flags register only reports the parity of the accumulator after an ALU operation.  On the Z-80 it reports parity for logical operations and overflow for arithmetic operations.
2. Half carry.  `RLC`, `RLCA`, `RL` and `RLA` clear the half-carry flag on the Z-80 while the 8080 leaves it unchanged.
3. Other flag bits.  The Z-80 adds the N flag which records whether the last arithmetic operation was an add or subtract (and is use by the `DAA` instruction).  The Z-80 preserves all flag bits so the flags register can take on any value after a `POP AF`.  The 8080 always sets unused flag bits to 1.
4. Instruction timings.  Incrementing or decrementing a register pair takes 6 cycles on the Z-80, 5 on the 8080.  Inc/dec of a single register is 4 cycles on the Z-80, 5 on the 8080 (or for (HL) 11 versus 10).  `ADD HL,rp` is 11 on the Z-80, 10 on the 8080.  Loading an 8 bit register from another is 4 on the Z-80, 5 on the 8080, but 8 bit load/store on (HL) is still 7 on both.  A conditional `CALL` not-taken is 10 on the Z-80, 11 on the 8080.  `ex sp,(hl)` is 19 on the Z-80, 18 on the 8080.  `jp (hl)` is 4 on the Z-80, 5 on the 8080.  `ex de,hl` is 4 on the Z-80, 5 on the 8080.  `ld sp,hl` is 6 on the Z-80, 5 on the 8080.
5. `DAA`.  On the 8080 this only works after addition (as it lacks the `N` flag to tell the difference).  It may also differ when given unusual inputs.

Most of the additional Z-80 opcodes are prefixed by bytes `CB`, `DD`, `ED` and `FD` which the 8080 treats as aliases for other instructions.

The `CB` series are shift, rotate and bit test instructions: `RLC`, `RRC`, `RL`, `RR`, `SLA`, `SRA`, `SRL`, `BIT`, `SET`, `RES` and the undocumented `SL1`.

The `DD` and `FD` series are used for any operations on the `IX` and `IY` registers respectively.

The `ED` series are a mixed set of extensions prominently featuring the block move instructions:

```
IN r,(C)
OUT (C),r
SBC HL,rp
ADC HL,rp
LD (nn),rp
LD rp,(nn)
NEG
RETN
IM 0/1/2
LD I,A
LD A,I
LD R,A
LD A,R
RETI
RRD
RLD
LDI
LDIR
LDD
LDDR
CPI
CPIR
CPD
CPDR
INI
INIR
IND
INDR
OUTI
OTIR
OUTD
OTDR
```

Note that `RLC`, `RLCA`, `RRC`, `RRCA` are single opcode instructions shared by both.  Similarly, both have a single opcode `LD HL,(nn)` and `LD (nn),HL` while only the Z-80 has the redundant `ED` version of `LD HL,(nn)` and `LD (nn),HL`.

Finally, the Z-80 has several new single-byte opcodes:

```
08   EX AF,AF'
10   DJNZ
18   JR off
20   JR NZ,off
28   JR Z,off
30   JR NC,off
38   JR C,off
D9   EXX
```

The Z-80 does not have a new `JP` instruction that tests the overflow flag.  This remains the conditional jump based on parity but the "parity" bit is set based on overflow for arithmetic instructions.  It just looks that way because Z-80 assemblers accept both `JP PO`,`JP PE` and `JP V`,`JP NV,` to allow the programmer to express intent.

The 8085 processor extends the 8080 instruction set with entirely different single-byte opcodes.

A good handful of the new Z-80 instructions deal with new interrupt handling modes.  If you're looking to port Z-80 code to 8080 there is a relatively short list of things to watch out for:

1. Any use of `IX`, `IY`, `AF'`, `BC'`, `DE'`, `HL'`
2. Auto-increment/decrement instructions like `LDI`, `LDIR`.
3. Relative jumps
4. Bit test/set/reset and shifts.  Rotates on any register but `A`.
5. 16 bit add with carry or subtract with carry.
6. Use of overflow (generally uncommon)

Comment: This has nothing to do with the *difference* between 8080 and Z80, but I'll note here that the actual implementation of IX and IY on the Z80 is that they parallel the HL register set. The 0xDD and 0xFD prefix bytes simply cause the remaining instruction to operate on IX or IY instead of HL, and that *includes* operations on either H or L, so you can split the registers into two 8-bit partitions.

Comment: Besides this, there's a gap in the rotate instruction table: there is SLA or Shift Left Arithemtic, SRA (Shift Right Arithmetic), and SRL (SR Logical); but then there are 8 "unused" opcodes that would be "SLL" but there's no reason to have a "logical" left shift as that's identical to arithmetic left shift. The oddity is that the gap opcodes *do* shift left, but insert a constant 1 bit (not a copy of the sign bit). In the assembler I wrote for myself I called this the `SLI` or Shift Left Illogical operation. :-) (I also called the halves of IX and IY, `IXH`, `IXL`, `IYH`, and `IYL`.)

Comment: A quick way to detect if code is running on an 8080 or a Z80 is to use the difference in the way the parity flag behaves:

        `SUB A ! JP PE, IS_8080`

Comment: "It may also differ when given unusual inputs." I've made some checks comparing some Z80 emulator (specifically, from Unreal Speccy emulator, able to pass ZEXALL test) and the algorithm derived from transistor-level model of i8080 (reverse-engineered by Vslav) and got exactly the same results for DAA for every combination of input C flag, H flag and accumulator contents (checking only additions so N=0 for Z80). The result i've been comparing were carry and resulting accumulator.

Answer (score 20):

This document calls out some differences:

http://www.msxarchive.nl/pub/msx/mirrors/hanso/datasheets/chipsz80leventhal3.pdf

1. Z80 uses P flag for 2's complement overflow, where 8080 does not
2. DAA instruction corrects both subtraction as well as addition on Z80, but addition only on 8080.
3. Z80 rotate instructions clear the A<sub>C</sub> flag, but the 8080 does not.

Also, timings are different per-instruction.

Comment: Good reference.  I added the half-carry difference to my long-winded answer and made the `DAA` change certain.

Comment: Do you think you could include all of the relevant information from the document? There's a lot more than that in the source you cite.

Comment: This does cover what instructions are on the 8080 and different on the Z80, not the other way round. The Z80 added, among others,  a lot of powerful block commands the 8080 didn't have: LDIR, DJNZ, LDDR, CPDR, the second register set,...